# Blog error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building the view post page for my blog and I have the following error in the browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM blog_posts
>   WHERE postID = '15'' at line 1' in
>   /home/ct5006kwolczak/public_html/viewpost.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/ct5006kwolczak/public_html/viewpost.php(7):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/ct5006kwolczak/public_html/viewpost.php on line 7

I expect the page to view the post description page

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TUum.png)

Comment: Remove comma before `FROM` clause

Comment: add code in question. don't add code picture

Comment: Don't add screenshots of code - it's annoying!  As for an error remove the comma `postdate, FROM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in query string syntax:

```
Remove comma after `postDate` field.
```

Comment: Thank you @SergeantDom accepting my answer.